# When should I delete my posts?

Tags: discussion, up-votes, self-answer, vote-to-delete

I have posted a few times and answered my own questions. Normally it was because I was overlooking something or just plain doing something stupid.  So I deleted the post thinking it would not benefit anybody else.  What is the MO for keeping your posts?  At the same time I am afraid if I answer my own posts (because I truly found an answer) then people may vote my answer down, when in fact I was keeping it up in case it helped someone else.

Can an answer to your own post even be voted up by another person?

Comment: as usual, please make your post a community-wiki one (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212942/why-should-stack-overflow-faq-be-community-owned)

Answer (score 17):

Deleting your posts when it is not helpful, or not relevant, or when it is contained inside another answer is a good idea, and removes clutter in general.

It is actually stated in the FAQ that answering your own questions is OK.  And you can even obtain a badge for it if you have 3 up votes on an answer to your own question. 
(Self-Learner badge: Answered your own question with at least 3 up votes)

But if you have any kind of value in your question/answer, even if you answered your own question, you should keep it up.   Even when your answer is not the best, and even if it has 0 votes, it might help someone who finds the answer and has a slightly different problem than the person who accepted the other answer had.

2 other badges worth mentioning around this topic are:

- Peer Pressure: Deleted own post with 3 or more downvotes
- Disciplined: Deleted own post with 3 or more upvotes

These 2 badges are to encourage deletion of posts that are just bloating the system I presume.

Answer (score 2):

Oh also, if you delete it after having received some down votes, then you get a "Peer Pressure" badge. I just got one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes an answer to your own question can be voted up.

If your answer is something that could be helpful to somebody else, then definitely leave it.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't delete your own posts unless the question has been downvoted - add your answer and let others learn from it!